# How can I set a Membership to Next Year?

Tags: civimember

The business rule is that if people join after September this year, their membership becomes effective for the next calendar year.

Can this be done within CiviCRM?

At the moment we are adjusting the dates with a hook.

```
civicrmprofile_civicrm_postProcess {
  if ($join_date_month > 9) {
        $end_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($join_date_year + 1 . "-12-31"));
        $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($join_date_year . "-01-01"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - in Membership Types you can set membership type plan to be fixed, and then set the Start Day and also set the Rollover day

> Membership signups on or after this date cover the following calendar year as well. Example: If the rollover day is November 30, membership period for signups during December will cover the following year.